# Add incremental option to markdown tables in Rmarkdown with reveal.js

Tags: css, r-markdown, pandoc, quarto, reveal.js

I have a table like that that I render on a slide with Rmarkdown into a reveal.js html presentation:

```
|variable           |class     |description        |
|:------------------|:---------|:------------------|
|character_1_gender |character |The gender of the older character, as identified by the person who submitted the data for this couple| 
|character_2_gender |character |The gender of the younger character, as identified by the person who submitted the data for this couple|
```

In other parts, I use the incremental option to let list items appear after each other as fragments:

```
:::incremental
- The two (or more) actors play actual love interests (not just friends, coworkers, or some other non-romantic type of relationship)

- The youngest of the two actors is at least 17 years old

- Not animated characters
:::
```

How can I create a new class `incremental_table` that treats each table row as a fragment and can otherwise be used just as in the list example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is a starting point for you. You can solve this manually using raw HTML code, e.g.

```
---
format: revealjs
---

## Incremental

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>variable</th>
      <th>class</th>
      <th>description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="fragment" data-fragment-index="1">
      <td>character_1_gender</td>
      <td>character</td>
      <td>The gender of the older character, as identified by the person who submitted the data for this couple</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fragment" data-fragment-index="2">
      <td>character_2_gender</td>
      <td>character</td>
      <td>The gender of the younger character, as identified by the person who submitted the data for this couple</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, that sounds good! do you maybe know how :::incremental ... ::: works? how it adds the fragment class to every list element? I would really like to adapt that to be able to continue to use markdown tables instead of html ones on my slides

Comment: I began switching to Quarto now, which has a number of new functionalities already in-built
Tables are also much better supported now, I'll try to find a solution in the future with Quarto